# seems to be a bug in nvd3 lineWithFocusChart for small set of data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Please see the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/tO5IgK2Bcx5fDKXCkFgH?p=preview. Initially there are so many repetitions of x-ticks for the same data value. Then, when I select Date Range slider, main chart x-ticks are getting changed to some peculiar dates like 01/01/70, etc. Purposely I have given small data set. Even though the data is in standard format lineWithFocusChart is not working properly, how can fix this? Is it a bug in nvd3 lineWithFocusChart?

```
     $scope.data = [
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "series": 0,
        "y": 0.3,
        "x": 1394841600000
      },
      {
        "series": 0,
        "y": 0.3,
        "x": 1394928000000
      }
    ],
    "key": "ABC"
  }
];
```

**Note : I have commented large data set in my plunker. For large data set lineWithFocusChart is working fine.**

Comment: All your dates have a couple of days gaps between them.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear, could you please explain little bit more how can I fix it. My expectation is, whatever dates I have those have to be properly divided under x-ticks and relevant y axis values have to be properly plotted.

Comment: @ shabeer90, I have only two dates here, "x": 1394841600000 and "x": 1394928000000. What do you mean, that these days have couple of days gaps between them? Could you please, clarify me this? Thanks.